# Don't know which kernel to remove to free up disk space

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I'm having an issue. I'm trying to install `webmin` but I keep getting `Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`.

Now after doing some reading I see that disk space might be an issue:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-92-generic i686)                                                                                                                                            

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/                                                                                                                                                                 

  System information as of Wed Jan 25 08:36:03 SAST 2017                                                                                                                                                    

  System load:  0.15               Processes:           101                                                                                                                                                 
  Usage of /:   31.1% of 69.06GB   Users logged in:     0                                                                                                                                                   
  Memory usage: 23%                IP address for eth0:                                                                                                                                           
  Swap usage:   0%                                                                                                                                                                                          

  => /boot is using 99.6% of 235MB       



linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic                                                                                                                                                                        
initramfs-tools                                                                                                                                                                                            
proxy-admin@ubuntu-Server:~$ du -h --ma-depth=1 | sort -hr                                                                                                                                                  
du: unrecognized option '--ma-depth=1'                                                                                                                                                                      
Try 'du --help' for more information.                                                                                                                                                                       
proxy-admin@ubuntu-Server:~$ sudo df -i                                                                                                                                                                     
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on                                                                                                                                                     
udev            207374     481  206893    1% /dev                                                                                                                                                           
tmpfs           212407     430  211977    1% /run                                                                                                                                                           
/dev/dm-0      4612096 2062528 2549568   45% /                                                                                                                                                              
none            212407       2  212405    1% /sys/fs/cgroup                                                                                                                                                 
none            212407       4  212403    1% /run/lock                                                                                                                                                      
none            212407       1  212406    1% /run/shm                                                                                                                                                       
none            212407       2  212405    1% /run/user                                                                                                                                                      
/dev/sda1        62248     336   61912    1% /boot                                                                                                                                                          
proxy-admin@ubuntu-Server:~$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image- ##identify all installed kernel images


**rc  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic        3.13.0-24.47                     i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                              
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic        3.13.0-79.123                    i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                              
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic        3.13.0-83.127                    i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                              
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-85-generic        3.13.0-85.129                    i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                              
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-86-generic        3.13.0-86.131                    i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                              
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-87-generic        3.13.0-87.133                    i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                              
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-88-generic        3.13.0-88.135                    i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                              
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-91-generic        3.13.0-91.138                    i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                              
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic        3.13.0-92.139                    i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                              
iU  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-107-generic 3.13.0-107.154                   i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                      
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic  3.13.0-24.47                     i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                      
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic  3.13.0-79.123                    i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                      
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-83-generic  3.13.0-83.127                    i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                      
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-85-generic  3.13.0-85.129                    i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                      
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-86-generic  3.13.0-86.131                    i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                      
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-87-generic  3.13.0-87.133                    i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                      
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-88-generic  3.13.0-88.135                    i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                      
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-91-generic  3.13.0-91.138                    i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                      
iF  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-92-generic  3.13.0-92.139                    i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                      
iU  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-93-generic  3.13.0-93.140                    i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP                                                      
iU  linux-image-generic                  3.13.0.107.115                   i386         Generic Linux kernel image** 




proxy-admin@ubuntu-Server:~$ sudo apt-get auto remove                                                                                                                                                       
E: Invalid operation auto                                                                                                                                                                                   
proxy-admin@ubuntu-Server:~$ sudo apt-get auturemove                                                                                                                                                        
E: Invalid operation auturemove                                                                                                                                                                             
proxy-admin@ubuntu-Server:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a                                                                                                                                                       
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.6) ...                                                                                                                                                             
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)                                                                                                                                                      
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-107-generic:                                                                                                                    
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-107-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-107-generic; however:                                                                                                                   
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-107-generic is not installed.                                                                                                                                                  

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-107-generic (--configure):                                                                                                                          
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured                                            
**strong text**
```

Comment: It's 'sudo apt-get autoremove'   you misspelled autoremove / auturemove !

Comment: You can manually remove files here, like from 3.13.0-24 to 3.13.0-87. Keep the last three or five, and see if that frees up enough space.

Comment: Take a look at this answer here for 14.04 kernels:  http://askubuntu.com/a/620281/231142

Answer (score 0):

I use this command to remove old kernels safely:

```
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-* | awk '/^ii/{print $2}' | egrep '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | grep -v $(uname -r) | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

see: [Bash one-liner to delete only old kernels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401581/bash-one-liner-to-delete-only-old-kernels)

Comment: But how do I know which kernel are old and which ones I should keep?

Comment: It excludes the current kernel with  `grep -v $(uname -r)`

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you [earned 15 reputation](/help/whats-reputation). Don't forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!

Comment: Thank you so so much carl, all is sorted now!!! you awesome!