# Error removing old kernel

Tags: kernel, software-uninstall

I need to make space in the boot but whatever I try to remove this old kernel returns an error.

[image: Tried to show results from synaptic and apt-get purge]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting, instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove old kernels with this:

```
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-* | awk '/^ii/{print $2}' | egrep '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | grep -v $(uname -r) | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

see: [Don't know which kernel to remove to free up disk space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876463/dont-know-which-kernel-to-remove-to-free-up-disk-space/876472)

The other errors you get (couldn't lock....) is because you have several applications running who are already created the lock.

Comment: Thanks Carl, I tried it but the error persist:

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-110-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: You'll need to remove files manually to hava some space in de boot dir.
See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute `apt-get` while synaptic is running.

Also try `apt-get autoremove` before anything else. On recent Ubuntu it removes most old kernels.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Marie. I noticed that I had synaptic opened and tried again. the result is on the second screenshot. The error seems to be a broken package

Answer (score 0):

I created a set of utilities to upgrade (Canonical precompiled), compile from source, and remove kernels.
Note the remove utility will remove all kernels except the current active one.

The scripts can also be called remotely through ssh.

https://github.com/mtompkins/linux-kernel-utilities

Comment: Thanks Mark. Tried it but error persist: 

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-110-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: I would try forcing a reinstall of that package `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-112-generic` with `dpkg`, rebooting then trying again. If memory serves, `dpkg --force-all`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following to take care of at least two of your problems.

**1)** In terminal:

```
cd /etc/apt/apt.conf.d  # change directory
ls -al                  # list all files
```

If `50unattended-upgrades` **does not exist**, we'll rename a file:

```
sudo mv 50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old 50unattended-upgrades
```

or if `50unattended-upgrades` **does exist**, we'll delete a file:

```
sudo rm -i 50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old
```

**2)** Your `/boot` partition is full. You need to delete some older linux kernels/etc there. I personally use Synaptic to do that work for me, but there are other methods that can be used. Search here on askubuntu if you need more help with this.